# Update one parameters of many of objects - the best way

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a situation to deliver solution for functionality of update one property of many objects. The point is that is possible to update any property. For example

```
class Book {
   private String name;
   private Long number;
   private LocalDate date;
   private SomeEnum name;
   private boolean someFlag;
}
```

Possible is to update only one field at a time, but each field is available to update.
Of course I can create new filter class with each field and send it with given parameter I'd like to update, but I thinking about more elegant solution. More generic.

I have to List get objects by ids from database, update and save all with updated field.

What do You think this could be done. Is possible to create filter class with one generic field depend on what variable user give to update? What is the best practice to do something like that ? What is you experience ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to normalise your data model.

Comment: Asking for the "best" of something without giving an exact metric for "best" is almost always opinion-based.

Comment: Anyway *don't* do this a row at a time in memory `update myTable set field = "newValue"` will update the value for all your instances in a single statement. Much faster.